# Python 3.6. base64 library

Tags: python, base64

I have a requirement to encode large files to text, then decode them back to binary. I'm using base from Python's standard library to do that. Some sample code:

```
def b64_check(file): #file is a String
    print('Decoding base64 file ' + file)
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        base64text = f.read()
    binary = b64decode(base64text)
    binaryname = file.replace('.b64','') #Files are named with a .b64 extension. ie, 'myapp.exe' encoded to base64 is saved in a text file name 'myapp.exe.b64'
    with open(binaryname, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(binary)
    os.remove(file)
```

I've tested this with files as large as 5GB with success. Is there are practical limit to the size of binary/text that the base64 library can encode/decode? Or is it limited just by the RAM in the host?

Is there a method that's faster or more memory-efficient? A library that reads a very large text file in chunks? Or one that can split a base64-encoded file into multiple files, then decode one at a time?

Comment: Which types of files you want to encode? It depends on that but you could use the pandas or the json lib. As mentioned before, it depends on the types of files

Comment: Literally every type of file. Part of my requirements is that any type of file can be sent. They could be text files (source code, csv's), various Office files (docx, xlsx), compressed archives (zip, tar.gz), compiled software (dll, exe) or other types. And it has to be converted to text, moved as a large text file, then decoded back to its original format.

Comment: Seems odd. Why do you need the data as "text"?

Comment: Well then I would highly suggest the request library for the purpose. And on the speed aspect: It depends on the way of transmission locally or through the internet? However, it is mostly RAM and internet dependent.

Comment: Long story, but to summarize: The files pass from one secure network to another through a gateway that only permits text to pass through.

Comment: How exactly is "text" defined there?

Comment: @christhebliss why would `pandas` or `json` be useful here?

Comment: I would look in to any utilities that exist for base64 encoding that are written for efficiency, e.g. https://github.com/aklomp/base64 (just an example, you'll need to do your own research). Python's implementation will probably not be the fastest / most memory efficient. And for these sorts of things, there is usually some highly-tuned C project that is used when speed and efficiency is of the essense

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd make sure it's a bottleneck, though, compared to reading/writing/transmitting files. Python's base64 gives me around [300 MB/s](https://tio.run/##lY@7DsIwDEX3fIU30qqiVK0qVKkLO9@AGuJCJPJQkg58fXAfCNZ68eNe@8juHZ/W1GfnUxq91RCVRhVBaWd93Dq2KGII2DZfRbQNmruVWMylxLlkm2YDYwJ6ysfJD0ZazatTnrcZY6P1cANlgOYP5HXWMaCI5F5Z/DVoIYfuB@AiK8BMWqDvq2yxO68MOdGQBiVtlyVU2BZwuF7KcCBOoIP/F3aS13942E9O6QM) on tio.run.

Comment: @KellyBundy yeah, absolutely. Premature optimization and all that.